# How to set "Theme my login" wordpress plugin as must use plugin (mu-plugins)?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Can any one help me for how I can make my TML(Theme My Login) wordpress plugin as Must Use plugin?
What changes are needed for the same ? 
Ref link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins
Thanks

Comment: Create a directory in wp-content called mu-plugins and put the plugin in this directory

Comment: Do we have to upload entire plugin folder or just activation hook file? I tried by moving theme-my-login.php file in mu-plugin but that doesn't work :(

Comment: Take the plugin folder as it currently is in the plugins directory and move it to the new directory called mu-plugins